# Action parameter is always empty

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing, el, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to pass a parameter to an action in my bean:

```html
<p:commandButton action="#{criarContaBean.voltar(login)}"
            immediate="true" value="Cancelar">
```

And my 'voltar' method:

```
public String voltar(String tela) {
        return tela;
    }
```

But when i check the value of 'tela', is empty. Anything i'm missing?

Comment: Could we have more code? i.e.: How do you declare `login`?

Comment: Need to check the Scope of your ManagedBean if it is RequestScope then defiantly it will be empty.

Comment: Try it with `#{criarContaBean.voltar('testParam')}` and see what happens.